# Checkbox transitions not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with transitions with my checkbox. All I want to do is to dropdown menu **slowly** on low width resolution.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="header-nav">
                <input type="checkbox" id="header-nav-button">
                    <label for="header-nav-button">☰</label>
                </input>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="header-nav-links" id="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="header-nav-links about-us">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a class="header-nav-links">Our Services</a></li>
                    <li><a class="header-nav-links">Prices</a></li>
                    <li><a class="header-nav-links">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Input CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label{
font-size: 40px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #ed145b;
font-family: Lato;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 38px;
padding: 0 20px;}

input, label{
display: none;}
```

And my CSS code placed in @media (max-width: 600px):

```
label{
    display: inline-block;  
}

#header-nav-button{

}
#header-nav-button:not(:checked) ~ul{
    display:none;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
     -o-transition: all .5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
     transition: all 5s ease;
}

}
#header-nav-button:checked ~ ul{
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
}

#header-nav-button:checked ~ ul li{
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

I tried the trick with height, visibility and opacity - nothing worked for me unfortunatly. It seems that transition is just not working properly.

Comment: Have you tried fiddling around with the transition duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't animate `height`.
But you CAN animate `max-height`.

```
<nav class="header-nav">
  <label for="header-nav-button">☰</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="header-nav-button">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="header-nav-links" id="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="header-nav-links about-us">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a class="header-nav-links">Our Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="header-nav-links">Prices</a></li>
    <li><a class="header-nav-links">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I positioned label above input so I can use the more precise `+` selector in CSS (`#header-nav-button + ul`)

```
label {
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ed145b;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

input,
label {
  display: none;
}

@media ( max-width: 600px) {
  label {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
  }
  ul li {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  #header-nav-button:checked+ul {
    max-height: 999px;
  }
}
```

I removed the `display` attributes because you can't animate display. Instead, I used `overflow: hidden` to hide the menu.
And I changed `height` to `max-height`. The good thing about this, is you don't need to know the exact height of the menu, you can set it to an amount you know it will never reach. This way you're menu can "grow" without you having to figure out its height every time.

https://jsfiddle.net/w4fwbw3s/8/

Comment: I also changed the selectors inside the media query. Don't use ```#header-nav-button:not(:checked) ~ul``` but just use ```ul```

Comment: You can animate height - it's just harder to do as you have to know the exact height

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It worked out! All I had to add to your code is "width: 100%" for li, to make it appear as blocks. Thank you so much :)